# Extract tweet replies from list of tweet ids

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter, scrape

I have few list of tweet IDs and i want to scrape all the replies. Is there any way to do it? I tried beautifulsoup and selenium but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Twitter has an API that can accomplish this.

You'll want to use this:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/lookup/api-reference/get-tweets-id

It looks like you'll need to use "includes" or "includes.tweets" field toward the bottom of the page. You'll need to sign up for a dev account and create a dev app but it's all free and doesn't take much time. Also, all the example code is in Java and Typescript but you should be able do everything in Python using the "requests" library.

I think you need to apply for an "Elevated" dev account to use v2 but I don't remember. I applied and got accepted instantly so it shouldn't be a problem either way. Once you've created your app, copy your Bearer token so you can make API requests in Python. You'll be making GET requests and providing your Bearer token in the headers. Here's the gist of what it will look like: https://reqbin.com/req/python/5k564bhv/get-request-bearer-token-authorization-header-example

Example query:

`https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/{tweet_id}?expansions=author_id&tweet.fields=created_at`